# How can i access to the best estimator params in a model that is contained in a pipeline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have the following sklearn pipeline:

```
Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('feature_processor', DataProcessor()),
            ('classifier', GridSearchCV(cv=15,
                                        error_score='raise-deprecating',
                                        estimator=XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5,
                                                                booster='gbtree',
                                                                colsample_bylevel=1,
                                                                colsample_bynode=1, 
                                                                colsample_bytree=1,
                                                                gamma=0, learning_rate=0.1,
                                                                max_delta_step=0,..._dispatch='2*n_jobs',
                                                                refit=True,
                                                                return_train_score='warn',
                                                                scoring='accuracy', verbose=1))
            ])
```

There is a trained model inside, which parameters were optimized using `GridSearchCV`. The model with its pipeline were saved into a pickle. I'm using `pickle.load()` to read it back, but now i just don't know how to access the best params that were found by `GridSearchCV`.

Can please someone point me in the right direction?

If it was not possible to access this information via the pipe's info, would there be any other way to do this?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: was the answer helpful?

Comment: Yes, it was, sorry, i forgot to accept but now is ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
pipeline.named_steps['classifier'].best_params_
```

Answer (score 2):

From your example, you can get the best model by:

```
loaded_pipe = pickle.load(open("<your_pkl_file>", 'rb'))
loaded_pipe['classifer'].best_estimator_
```

Edit:

Only for best parameters:

```
loaded_pipe['classifer'].best_params_
```